# Jquery mobile - data-role="none" not working sometimes

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a really strange behavior on my app. I have a navigation for the page divs. On the first page I have the rateit plugin active. If I reload the first page with the #one in url, the data-role="none" is ignored. this has been driving me nuts the whole day, I tried to setup an jsfiddle but since I need the rateit plugin also, I couldn't.

My app have a simple navigation with link buttons and a cancel button, which fires a ResetAll() javascript function.

Here is the code:

**page header**

```
<script src="assets/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
        $.extend( $.mobile , {
            ignoreContentEnabled : true
        });
    });
</script>   
<script src="assets/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

The rateit stars container within the div `<div data-role="page" id="one">`

```
    <div class="rateit bigstars" id="rateitcontainer" data-rateit-step="1" 
data-rateit-starwidth="128" data-rateit-starheight="128" 
data-rateit-resetable="false" data-role="none"></div>
```

**The cancel button**

```
<p><a href="#cancel" class="button floated smallbutton" data-role="button" data-theme="e" onclick="ResetAll()">cancel</a></p>
```

And the reset-all function

```
function ResetAll() {
    window.location.href = "#one";
    location.reload(true);
};
```

When I am loading the page like this domain.com/#one (what happens after the reload) there is this ugly div above the stars, and I can't get rid of it! Please help someone!

[image: screenshot so should it be]

[image: after clicking on english flag, now with /#one-en in url]

Comment: If you can't set up a jsfiddle example, can you at least include a screenshot of what the out of place div looks like?

Comment: @Derek thank you I added a screenshot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok this is just nuts and crazy, I am sure I tried this already before, but now its working.

The `data-role="none"` is not working because the `div` is not a JQM widget, thus not applied.

The `div` needs **`data-enhance="false"`** to be not styled!
I learned this on the jQuery forum. No idea why I did it not get to work earlier...